# $(this) not selecting element in callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 different set of codes, the only difference is the location of `$(this).closest('.organizer_listing').slideUp('fast');`. In the first set of code, it works, but I prefer for that line of code to be as in the 2nd set of code inside the callback function, which no longer works - `slideUp` does not seem to be executed.

Why is this so? How should I fix it?

**Variation 1**

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
    $(this).closest('.organizer_listing').slideUp('fast');  // Remove listings visually from list
    // Send AJAX request to delete from database
    var listing_id = $(this).closest('.organizer_listing').data('listing_id');
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.getJSON(base_url + 'organizer/delete_favorite',
        {listing_id: listing_id},
        function(json) {
            $.modal.close();
    });
});
```

**Variation 2**

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
    // Send AJAX request to delete from database
    var listing_id = $(this).closest('.organizer_listing').data('listing_id');
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.getJSON(base_url + 'organizer/delete_favorite',
        {listing_id: listing_id},
        function(json) {
            $.modal.close();
            $(this).closest('.organizer_listing').slideUp('fast');  // Remove listings visually from list
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variation two doesn't work because in your `$.getJSON` callback, `this` is no longer the current element in your `each` loop, but rather the `jqXHR` object.

You can easily work around this by saving the value of `this` to a new variable, which your callback will "close over" (have access to):

```
var self = this;
$.getJSON(base_url + 'organizer/delete_favorite',
        {listing_id: listing_id},
        function(json) {
            $.modal.close();
            $(self).closest('.organizer_listing').slideUp('fast');  // Remove listings visually from list
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work anymore because `this` in the callback of the `$.getJSON` is not anymore your checkbox !

Do this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {

    var $cb = $(this); // save your ref to the checkbox

    var listing_id = $cb.closest('.organizer_listing').data('listing_id');
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $.getJSON(base_url + 'organizer/delete_favorite',
        {listing_id: listing_id},
        function(json) {
            $.modal.close();

            // use $cb
            $cb.closest('.organizer_listing').slideUp('fast');

    });
});
```

When you want to use it, you should always ask yourself what is the value of `this` in the current context.